# Statically-defined routes for @page in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages v6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

My ASP.NET Core 6 RazorPage has this:

```
@page "/foo/bar"
```

I want to define that statically, like so:

```
@page @MyConstants.Pages.Foo.Bar
```

But that doesn't work.

There are some [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941524/strongly-typed-route-in-page-directive-in-razor-pages) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894753/blazor-page-route-url-define-with-variable) about this, but none have working solutions - perhaps they are for older versions. I tried all the recommended approaches:

```
@page [Route(MyConstants.Pages.Foo.Bar)]
```

and

```
@page [Route(route)]
@functions { public const string route = MyConstants.Pages.Foo.Bar; }
```

and

```
@attribute [RazorCompiledItemMetadata("RouteTemplate", MyConstants.Pages.Foo.Bar)]
```

How can I do this for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages **version 6**? (Note: not Blazor, but RazorPages specifically, which apparently has subtle differences in this regard.)

Comment: Sorry, there doesn't seem to be any official documentation to apply this Blazor property to RazorPage, so it may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `@page`:

```
@page
@attribute [RazorCompiledItemMetadata("RouteTemplate", MyConstants.Pages.Foo.Bar)]
```

The `Route` attribute works for `.razor` pages, but not `.cshtml`.

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote above, I tried that without success. Did it work for you?

Comment: In your example, the @page was missing. Yes it does work for me, but when using `href`, not with `asp-page`.